# Reactjs using typescript render output html formatting

Tags: reactjs, typescript

why does the following render cause problems.  I'm simply trying to output two rows of the same data.  It compiles fine, but in my output the two rows of tbody data align to the first column (make) and the rest of the headers are aligned to the right of the two rows of tbody data.  I'm just simplifying this code to test with, but ultimately what I want is a second row that has an input field for each column.  The input field will allow me to change the corresponding cell value.

I also get:

```
warning.js:35 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. See CarTool > tbody > div. 

warning.js:35 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>. See CarTool > div > tr.

public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Car Tool</h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Make</td>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>Year</td>
                        <td>Color</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.cars.map((car) =>
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{car.make}</td>
                                <td>{car.model}</td>
                                <td>{car.year}</td>
                                <td>{car.color}</td>
                                <td>{car.price}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{car.make}</td>
                                <td>{car.model}</td>
                                <td>{car.year}</td>
                                <td>{car.color}</td>
                                <td>{car.price}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>,
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>;
    }
```

Make    Model   Year    Color   Price
Ford    Edge    2016    white   42000
Ford    Edge    2016    white   42000
Ford    Ranger  2006    white   10000
Ford    Ranger  2006    white   10000
Chevy   Malibu  2012    blue    32000
Chevy   Malibu  2012    blue    32000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{this.props.cars.map((car, index) =>
                    [
                        <tr key={"value" + index}>
                            <td>{car.make}</td>
                            <td>{car.model}</td>
                            <td>{car.year}</td>
                            <td>{car.color}</td>
                            <td>{car.price}</td>
                        </tr>,
                        <tr key={"input" + index}>
                            <td>{car.make}</td>
                            <td>{car.model}</td>
                            <td>{car.year}</td>
                            <td>{car.color}</td>
                            <td>{car.price}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ],
                )}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked perfect. i'm familiar with the need for an index, i was just putting this together quickly to test.  but where is the syntax for rendering multiple rows documented?  i want to read upon it.  i wouldn't have thought do this based on my limited knowledge thus far of react.

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid syntax to have a `div` element as a child of a `tbody`.

```
<tbody>
    {this.props.cars.map((car) =>
        <tr>
            <td>{car.make}</td>
            <td>{car.model}</td>
            <td>{car.year}</td>
            <td>{car.color}</td>
            <td>{car.price}</td>
        </tr>
    )}
</tbody>
```

Also, don't forget to include `key` for each element, since you are dynamically creating them via `map`.